# Reg Ex to replace single quote up to a constant

Tags: shell, sed, awk

I have a csv file that I need to load into postgres.

The values look like

```
Date, Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4
20140101,value1, value2, value3, "http//,bar"
20130102,value1, value2, value3, "http//,bar"
20130103,value1, value2", value3, "http//,XXX"
```

In some of my data (as shown on line 3) I have some bad data where `value2` has a double quote at the end of it.

Unfortunately I have no control over the input data.

using the postgres COPY command "as csv"   I get an error unterminated quote.

I cannot remove all quotes in the file because of the last column 4 has commas embedded in the value and the comma is my delimiter.

Basically what I'm looking for is some type of SED script that can delete all occurrences of a double quote UP until the first occurence of "http//.....   The last column will always have "http//"  in it so I'm good using that as a constant.

In the example above lines 1 and 2 are correct. Line 3 should change from

```
20130103,value1, value2", value3, "http//,XXX"
```

to

```
20130103,value1, value2, value3, "http//,XXX"
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be much easier using perl since it supports lookahead:

```
perl -pe 's/"(?=.*?"http)//g' file.csv
Date, Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4
20140101,value1, value2, value3, "http//,bar"
20130102,value1, value2, value3, "http//,bar"
20130103,value1, value2, value3, "http//,XXX"
```

OR using awk:

```
awk -F'"http' 'index($1, "\"") { gsub(/"/, "", $1); $1=$1 FS } 1' file
Date, Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4"http
20140101,value1, value2, value3, "http //,bar"
20130102,value1, value2, value3, "http //,bar"
20130103,value1, value2, value3, "http //,XXX"
```

Comment: I used the perl solution and works great!  Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to know, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;s|"(.*"http//)|\1|;ta' file
```